# clearInterval and eventListener

Tags: event-handling, setinterval, clearinterval

My problem is, I'm not being able to use the 'setInterval' attached to a button and use another one to stop it with 'clearInterval'.

My thought process:
Since clearInterval() would need a target, I stored the setInterval() inside a variable. However, I noticed that setInterval() starts running without being triggered by the eventListener attached to it. I was expecting this behaviour of firing on its own only if I had put setInterval() out in the open without being stored on a variable and on the global scope.

So then I tried to encapsulate it inside  a function, only this time the clearInterval() seemed to 'lose' the target.

I had a look on some situtations and couldn't find an explanation that would satisfy my case. Right now it looks like I can't have both ways (a btn to 'fire' the timer and a btn to shut it off).

I don't know if this is a matter of scope,event handling or targeting. Had a look on [HTMLStandard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#dom-clearinterval) but couldn't make much use of it.

Thank you

```
<script>
  let repeater = function () {
    setInterval(() => {
      console.log('loading');
    }, 1000);
  };

  const startButton = document.querySelector('#firstB');
  const stopButton = document.querySelector('#secondB');

  startButton.addEventListener('click', repeater);

  stopButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    clearInterval(repeater);
    console.log('finished');
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const startButton = document.querySelector("#firstB");

  const stopButton = document.querySelector("#secondB");

  let repeater;

  startButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
    repeater = setInterval(() => {
      console.log("loading");
    }, 1000);
  });

  stopButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    clearInterval(repeater);
    console.log("finished");
  });
```

This should work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).